# Win8(タブレット)向けWindowsデスクトップアプリにてカメラを利用する方法(package.appxmanifestの変更？)

Tags: windows, c++, visual-studio

タイトルの件となります。
WindowsデスクトップアプリでWinRTのAPIを利用できるということなので
https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/using-winrt-apis-from-desktop-applications

(利用可能なAPI一覧)
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn554295%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

をみて、MediaCaptureクラスを利用しようと考えたのですが、Windowsストアアプリなどではカメラの利用を許可するために「package.appxmanifest」を変更していると思います。
デスクトップアプリの場合はどのようにすればカメラが利用できるのでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

C#とVBですが[MSDNの日本フォーラム](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ja-JP/ebc89f7d-d6d6-4490-9602-088d84501d01)にMediaCaptureを使用したデスクトップアプリのサンプルコードがあり、githubからプロジェクト一式を入手できます。
サンプルではストアアプリのような許可は行わずにカメラを使用できています。

C++では以下のように読み替えるのだと考えられます。

- vcxprojを編集してTargetPlatformVersionを追加
- 以下のdllを参照
  System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.dll  System.Runtime.dll
  System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.dll
  System.Threading.Tasks.dll
  System.IO.dll
- Windows.winmdはプロジェクトのプロパティ->構成プロパティ->全般->Windowsストアアプリのサポート->[はい]で参照